# Change gps behaviour on build target compile file

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

If I use the GNAT Programming Studio (GPS) to build a single file (Build target Compile file), the editor jumps to the first location in the file with a build warning/error.

It is possible to disable this behaviour using a setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's apparently an "Advanced" feature, and a bit harder to find than other settings...

Open the `Preferences` dialog (`Edit -> Preferences`).
Next to the `search preference...` box, there's a menu icon. Click on it, and tick off the `Show advanced preferences` option. An `Advanced` category has now been added to the list on the left. In there, you will find a `Jump to first location` option.

Comment: Thank you. ;) Tricky to find, I tried the provided search function but the setting is only included in the search results when the advanced preferences are activated/shown.